# Making function in a typescript module available to razor component

Tags: typescript, kendo-ui, razor-pages

Just for background, I've recently migrated from pure JS to using Typescript.  I was making heavy use of IFFEs, and was able to keep things working by using namespaces.

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-namespace */+
//util.ts
namespace common {

    export const util = (function () {
        'use strict';

        //onload stuff
        $(function () {
            //placeholder but probably won't add anything here
        });

        function getQueryStringParm(name) {

            const params = new Proxy(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search), {
                get: (searchParams, prop) => searchParams.get(prop.toString()),
            });

            return params[name];
        }

        function buttonClick() {
            return "button clicked!";
        }

        // Public
        return {
            getQueryStringParm,
            buttonClick
        };
    })();

}
```

I can call the above from the console or more importantly, from a razor component like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("create-button")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button" })
    .Content("Button")
    .Events(e => e.Click("common.util.buttonClick"))
    )
```

So this is all working, but I'm under the impression that it's a bad practice and I want to address that now, while this project is still relatively small.

I've tried converting to modules and I have no problem with code working between the modules, using imports.  But where I keep getting stuck is being able to call the function from the razor view.  Any suggestions?

I tried to create test file ... testmod.ts, without any namespace:

```
export module testmod {
    export function getQueryStringParm(name) {

        const params = new Proxy(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search), {
            get: (searchParams, prop) => searchParams.get(prop.toString()),
        });

        return params[name];
    }

    export function buttonClick() {
        return "button clicked!";
    }

}
```

then add it to the view like this:

`<script src="~/js/test/testmod.js" type="module"></script>`

This didn't work (testmod undefined error), and my IDE complains that I should be using namespace instead so feels like I'm going down the wrong path anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by exposing an "init" method where I regisiter all the event handlers and then putting this at the bottom of my view:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        window.xxxxx.init();
    }
</script>
```

at the bottom of my ts module:

```
export const xxxxxxxxx = {
    init
};

// Attach util to the window object under a specific namespace
declare global {
    interface Window {
        xxxxxxxxx: any;
    }
}

window.xxxxxxxxx = window.xxxxxxxxx || {};
```